# fontsize fractions in the package siunitx

Tags: fontsize, siunitx, xfrac

I'm using the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to problems in physics, but to express the speed units in the style `\sfrac`, they are too small, how could slightly increase the size?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel,stmaryrd} %Soporte math símbolos-fonts.
\usepackage{siunitx, xfrac}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
   Mi coche viaja a 
   $75\si[per-mode=fraction,fraction-function = \sfrac]{\kilo\metre\per\hour}$, 
   durante $3\si{\hour}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use `\SI[...]{75}{\kilo\metre\per\hour}` instead of `75\si[...]{\kilo\metre\per\hour}` to get the spacing right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`xfrac`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) package permits to adjust the settings for `\sfrac` both in text and in math mode.

In math mode, the scaling of numerator and denominator is done with (the default is `0.7`):

```
\DeclareCollectionInstance{plainmath}{xfrac}{mathdefault}{math}
{
scale-factor = 0.9
}
\UseCollection{xfrac}{plainmath}
```

So, the following MWE should give the desired result (I've used `\SI` instead of `\si` for better spacing):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel,stmaryrd} %Soporte math símbolos-fonts.
\usepackage{siunitx, xfrac}
\usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareCollectionInstance{plainmath}{xfrac}{mathdefault}{math}
{
scale-factor = 0.9
}
\UseCollection{xfrac}{plainmath}

\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,fraction-function=\sfrac}

\begin{document}
   Mi coche viaja a
   $\SI{75}{\kilo\metre\per\hour}$,
   durante $\SI{3}{\hour}$.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: is it just me or is the spacing between the fraction and `75` a bit small?

Comment: @daleif IMHO, it is just you :-)

Comment: It just seems smaller than in `\SI{3}{\hour}`